# Rename the index with Sequel migration

Tags: mysql, ruby, postgresql, sequel

I am trying to rename indexes in mysql database with sequel migration. I am converting mysql to postgresql. Postgres has only 63 chars for indexes. I don't want to let pgloader truncate them.

Is there any way to use mysql statement `RENAME INDEX`?

Comment: for the most part index names are unimportant (the only time you use the name is to drop the index)

Comment: I know, but when my index is truncated to 63 chars during conversion, we are unsure with uniqueness and we would like to have a control over this process, performed only one time. It is huge database project.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.7 or newer is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME INDEX old_index TO new_index
```

older versions:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP INDEX old_index_name, ADD INDEX new_index_name ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do it in mysql but I am looking for Sequel migration to do this. Our system is dependant on doing everything via particular migration.